# Hololens 2 development mode

Tags: hololens

If I would buy a HoloLens 2 (device only option):

- Can we configure the HoloLens 2 in developer mode and use Visual Studio, Unity and Azure for development?
- Does HoloLens 2 include a 365 remote assistance license?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone may mention that this isn't the place for these types of questions, however I'd like to answer them.

Any HoloLens 2 device, regardless of what type it is listed as on the https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/buy site can have developer mode enabled, and can be used for development.

Following to the next question, I believe the sales option on the far left includes a Dynamics 365 Remote Assist license.
If you want some quick links to learning more about license required you can check out the ones from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-licenses-requirements#remote-assist-license-requirements
I also think it's worth mentioning that you can use Remote Assist as a trial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/remote-assist/try-remote-assist